# how to coerce to specific subtype from union type

Tags: typescript

```
type example = {
    name : string | number | null
}
type processNumber = {
    name : number
}

const a : example = {
    name : 123
} as const
function PROCESS (input : processNumber) {
    console.log(input.name)
}

PROCESS(a);
```

I currently get the error

```
Argument of type 'example' is not assignable to parameter of type 'processNumber'.
  Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

How do coerce `name` to be of type `number`? Let us also assume that there are many more properties that need to be coerced, so anything that can quickly coerce (inline maybe) would be good.

Comment: Maybe something like `PROCESS(a as processNumber );` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is very easy:

```js
type example = {
    name: string | number | null
}
type processNumber = {
    name: number
}

const a = {
    name: 123
} as const satisfies example

function PROCESS(input: processNumber) {
    console.log(input.name)
}

PROCESS(a);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGA0vN)

All you need to do is to use [satisfies](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator) operator. It allows you to check whether it is satisfies some particular type and also makes type inference.

Please keep in mind that `satisfies` was provided in most recent version 4.9 of typescript.

Also, since you are using `as const` assertion, you can get rid of `satisfies`, but also you have to get rid of explicit type annotation, like here:

```js
const a = {
    name: 123
} as const
```

Comment: I like the `satisfies` operator, as it allows me to use the explicit type annotation, which has type inferences